# How can I render a JSF component based on if the date is greater than today's date?

Tags: java, jsf, date, xhtml

i get a date from server side and how do I compare this in my xhtml code, so that if it is less than today's date, I'll render the panel, otherwise not.

Comment: one way to do it is to get both the date from server side and compare it in rendered=#{abc.todaydate le abc.theDate}.      Is there any way I can do this with javascript ?

Comment: Since you said you want to render JSF component, you actually need to have the comparison on the server side ( Date.after(someOtherDate) will give you boolean that you can use for it ). Otherwise "hidden" component will still be visible (one can always use "View Source"), which poses security problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a method in your bean

```
class MyBean{    
  public boolean isDateBigger(){
   //date comparissoin and return result
  }
}
```

on XHTML

```
render="#{myBean.dateBigger}"
```

---

**Update:**

As per your comment, if you want to accomplish it through javascript then.

take two hidden parameter. 
One current millis and another representing your date's millis

compare them using javascript and apply DIV's style `visibility:hidden` to hide

Answer (score 1):

try

## {mbean.cardExpiryDate gt now}