# JSF 2.0 how to display element depending of the user right?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jaas

I am writing an application using JSF 2.0, java ee and glassfish.

My user interface is simple xhtml containing jsf.

I want my user to login and depending their right have different element displayed on the same pages.

is it possible using jaas ?

Thanks in advance
loic

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800724/how-can-i-render-a-jsf-component-based-on-if-the-date-is-greater-than-todays-dat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to write framework type code to do this "behind the scenes" you could bind the rendered attribute of the component to a method which checks the user's access rights e.g.

```
public boolean isUserAllowedAccess() {
        return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().
           isUserInRole("ROLE_ADMIN");
         // or whatever authorization code you want
    }
```

and then refer to it in the 'rendered' attribute of your JSF-tags e.g.

```
rendered="#{authBean.userAllowedAccess}"
```

You can wrap multiple components using panels e.g.

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{authBean.userAllowedAccess}">
```